# How do they animate falling raindrops on the  http://dropr.com site?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to know how this website http://dropr.com/ managed to get the cool floating clouds and colourful rainsdrops falling.

looks class

Comment: javascript (look at the source) they use mootool

Answer (score 3):

It uses JavaScript to continually change the `top` CSS value of the clouds. The drops are drawn on a stationary `<canvas>` which is behind the clouds.

Answer (score 1):

you can check it with any development tool like firebug o chrome tool but it was made with javascript, hare you have the animation code:

```
var t = 2000;

var animation1 = $('homeCloud1').getElement('div').animate()
.tween('top', -10, {
    duration: t
})
.delay(100)
.tween('top', 20, {
    duration: t
})
.repeat();
animation1.start();
```

Comment: I believe the file you seek is http://dropr.com/statik/main/js/homepageActions.js?1296650057

Answer (score 0):

The clouds are div elements that are moving. The raindrops are done via a <canvas> element.

Answer (score 0):

They used jQuery Mootools and associated animations to create that effect, you could replicate something very similar using jquery .animate(); and set it within a function for a constant loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is the HTML5 canvas element supported by modern browsers such as IE9, FF and Chrome. It also includes floating DIVS and some clever JS for the clouds.

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_canvas.asp